# Need help hosting an angular+php project

Tags: php, angularjs

http://www.angularcode.com/user-authentication-using-angularjs-php-mysql/

I'm trying to figure out how to host this Angular/PHP project on my local host. I'm a complete noob when it comes to PHP, would really appreciate any direction!

I tried putting it in a folder that had node and running a server with npm start, which shows me the files, but instead of running index.php, when I click that it downloads it to my machine.

I'm running on a mac OS and it seems I need to install PHP. Duh big first step there. Any particular recommendations?

Comment: It sounds like you don't have php installed or configured correctly.  Without knowing what OS you are serving it on, it's difficult to make a recommendation.  I suggest adding as many specifics as possible to your question, and since it is more server related than programming related, re-post your question on serverfault.com

Comment: thanks! Its not so much a server thing though as just getting able to host it on my computer for testing purposes so I can start doing a little devwork on it

Comment: I'm not familiar with OSX, but [this looks like a good place to start](http://php.net/manual/en/install.macosx.bundled.php).

Comment: is it running now ? I had the same problem but the one thing that you are doing wrong is running php code on npm so just paste the folder in htdocs of xampp and you are good to go! If you need help specifically with user authentication with angular.js PHP I can help :)